# Random Image Slider (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I have an image slider.

Unfortunately,
The image slider gets stuck on the second image.

I want the image slider to cycle through images in an infinite random loop.

How do I do this?

Here is my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/rAqcP/248/

*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*

**JS Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//$('.slider #1').show({right:'0'}, 500);
$('.slider #1').show('slide',{direction:'right'},500);
$('.slider #1').delay(5500).hide('slide',{direction:'left'},500);

var sliderTotalImg = $('.slider img').size();    
var counterIndex = 2;

setInterval(function () {

    //$('.slider #' + counterIndex).show({right:'0'}, 500);
    $('.slider #' + counterIndex).show('slide',{direction:'right'},500);
    $('.slider #' + counterIndex).delay(5500).hide('slide',{direction:'left'},500);

    if(count==slidecount){
count=1;

}else{
count=count+1;
}
},6500);});
```

**DIV CODE**

```
<div class = "slider">
<img id="1" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/images/Pokemon/001.png"/>
<img id="2" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/images/Pokemon/002.png"/>
<img id="3" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/images/Pokemon/003.png"/>
<img id="4" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/images/Pokemon/004.png"/>
</div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
.slider {
width: 20%;
height: 30%;
overflow:hidden;
border: 1px solid black;
background-image:url("http://test.softvex.com/Slider/Img/loading.gif");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center;
}

.slider img {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: What part of this is random?

Comment: If you are going to point us at a JSFiddle, it should be functional (i.e. should show the problem). Your JSFiddle is not.

Comment: Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/rAqcP/248/

Comment: You never define `slidecount`.  It is used only in your `if` statement. You never define `count`. Its first use is in the same `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never define `slidecount`.  It is used only in your `if` statement. You never define `count`. Its first use is in the same `if` statement.

I'm not sure if you did so, but you can watch the console output (keyboard shortcut <kbd>F12</kbd>) to see what errors occur in your code.  In your original code the error was that `count` was undefined. It only shows the first error, so it would have shown an error about `slidecount` after you fixed the one with `count`.

Note: There was nothing in your code that was random. So, I am unsure as to what you were intending to make random.

The following will work ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1cyr8w0c/)):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //$('.slider #1').show({right:'0'}, 500);
  $('.slider #1').show('slide', {
    direction: 'right'
  }, 500);
  $('.slider #1').delay(5500).hide('slide', {
    direction: 'left'
  }, 500);

  var sliderTotalImg = $('.slider img').size();
  var counterIndex = 2;
  var slidecount = 4;

  setInterval(function() {

    //$('.slider #' + counterIndex).show({right:'0'}, 500);
    $('.slider #' + counterIndex).show('slide', {
      direction: 'right'
    }, 500);
    $('.slider #' + counterIndex).delay(5500).hide('slide', {
      direction: 'left'
    }, 500);

    if (counterIndex >= slidecount) {
      counterIndex = 1;

    } else {
      counterIndex++;
    }
  }, 6500);
});
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 20%;
  height: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-image: url("http://test.softvex.com/Slider/Img/loading.gif");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}
.slider img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <img id="1" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/images/Pokemon/001.png" />
  <img id="2" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/images/Pokemon/002.png" />
  <img id="3" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/images/Pokemon/003.png" />
  <img id="4" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/BLANK-Theme/images/Pokemon/004.png" />
</div>
```